# Open GL ES 1 - How to know how many pixels on screen my Square/Cube will take up in 2D and 3D

Tags: opengl-es, coordinates

So first in 3D:
I have these vertices for my Cube

```
    float[] vertices = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                2.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                2.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
               -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,

                2.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                2.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                2.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                2.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,

                2.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1,
               -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1,
               -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1,
                2.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1,

               -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0,
               -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0,
               -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0,
               -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0,

               -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                2.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                2.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
               -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,

               -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0,
                2.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0,
                2.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0,
               -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0 };

        short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
                          4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4,
                          8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 8,
                          12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 12,
                          16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 16,
                          20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 20,
                          24, 25, 26, 26, 27, 24 };
```

So each one is 3 units wide (x-coord), going from -0.5 to 2.5.

Later on when I'm about to draw this, I have:

```
GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, glGraphics.getWidth(), glGraphics.getHeight());

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 67, glGraphics.getWidth() / (float) glGraphics.getHeight(), 0.1f, 10f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

This causes my square to take up I'd estimate 40-45% of my screen horizontally. I have no idea how it decides that 3 units equals 40-45% of my galaxy s3 in landscape mode. This just boggles my mind and it's something I just can't seem to grasp.

Also, does this work the same way when I draw in 2D? Or does it calculate it differently?

Thanks!

EDIT: So to expand on this in 2D, this is what I'm doing:

```
bobTexture = new Texture((GLGame)game, "bobrgb888.png");

        bobModel = new Vertices(glGraphics, 4, 12, false, true);
        bobModel.setVertices(new float[] { -16, -16, 0, 1,
                                            16, -16, 1, 1,
                                            16, 16, 1, 0,
                                            -16, 16, 0, 0}, 0, 16);
        bobModel.setIndices(new short[] {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0}, 0, 6);
```

And later:

```
GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0,  320, 0,  480, 1,  -1);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        bobTexture.bind();

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BOBS; ++i) { 
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glTranslatef(bobs[i].x, bobs[i].y, 0);
            bobModel.draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        }
```

bobs[i].x and bob[i].y are between 0 and 480 and 0 and 320.

Now when I do this, my Textured models end up being 32px x 32px. How?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs for gluLookAt.  Move the eye (first three parameters) around a little. The further away the eye is from the centre, the smaller it's going to appear.

Comment: Yeah I've been messing around with it since I asked this question and I've realized that this isn't really a good question in 3D because it depends on where it is in relation to the camera. However, I think the question still stands in 2D. Essentially what I want to do in 2D is I make a grid type structure using just triangles/indices. I want a set number of rows and columns but depending on the size of the screen horizontally and vertically, the  width of each column/row will be different. So how can I define in Model Space 2D and know what I'm going to see on the Screen in World  Space?